# Silverlight toolkit chart: axes do not always display 0 and maximum value

Tags: silverlight, charts, silverlight-toolkit

I am using the chart control provided in the silverlight toolkit.

I have defined 3 axes (code below). Now the series in the chart change at a user's command. Sometimes, the 0 value of the origin and the maximum axis value do not get displayed. They are not necessarily missing at the same time. I am out of idea on why this is happening. The values in the series are within the same range as they are bound on (0, 1000). Is this behaviour normal?

```
      <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis x:Name="LeftYAxis"
                                        Orientation="Y"
                                        Location="Left"
                                        BorderThickness="0.5"
                                        >

                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel" >
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
                                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                        <Border x:Name="AxisLabelMarker"
                                                Background="Transparent"
                                                BorderBrush="Blue"
                                                BorderThickness="0"
                                                >

                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                                       Grid.Column="0"
                                                       />
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
            </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>
            <chartingToolkit:CategoryAxis Orientation="X"
                                        Title="Percentage Increase in Bid Value"
                                        Location="Bottom"
                                        BorderThickness="0.5" 
                                       >

                <chartingToolkit:CategoryAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel" >
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
                                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                        <Border x:Name="AxisLabelMarker"
                                                Background="Transparent"
                                                BorderBrush="Blue"
                                                BorderThickness="0"
                                                >
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                                       Grid.Column="0"
                                                       />
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:CategoryAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
            </chartingToolkit:CategoryAxis>
            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis x:Name="RightYAxis"
                                        Orientation="Y"
                                        Location="Right"
                                        BorderThickness="0.5"
                                        >
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                               />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
            </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you specify the Minimum and Maximum values on the Axis the toolkit will automaticaly calculate values for them.  If I recall correctly from the last time I looked at teh source code it attempts to center the set values within a central 80% of the chart area, it adjust the Axis Minimum and Maximum values to acheive this.

Since you know that the range is (0, 1000) just add the appropriate `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties to the `LinearAxis`.